# Hibernate HQL record EXIST?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

To fetch recently added 21 records I am using:

```
String hql = "SELECT c from Model c WHERE c.status = true ORDER BY c.addedOn DESC";
            modelList = session.createQuery(hql).setMaxResults(21)
                    .getResultList();
```

now I have to see if the `modelList` contains a specific `Model`.

Is there a way in Hibernate to just return a boolean fuilfilling this requirement? You' ll be saving me a lot of time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What's the mark for specific model? Kind of like "name", "age", "country", or all of them. It's just like the equals() in Java. So you can put all the conditions to the HQL, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Model c WHERE c.status = true  AND name = 'aa' AND age = 20 AND country = 'BB'". It'll return 1 or 0 to you, not a list or an object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you missed a big part by leaving out `.setMaxResults(21)` and `ORDER BY c.addedOn DESC` .

Comment: You can also add these two requirements to HQL instead of querying 21 results and check

Comment: Not really @bejond ...the issue is, I couldn't find a way to write LIMIT query. The thing you are trying to tell me to do is really the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Got it, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) is what you looking for